# Resetting a wxPython app / destroying everything and starting from initial frame

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, instance

I've read other answers here, but they all seem to deal with just closing an app altogether, making sure all processes and frames and such are destroyed in the process. What I want to do is a little different.

My app consists of three frames (StartFrame, ParaFrame, ResultFrame) as well as a custom class for storing and manipulating data. The basics are: StartFrame is just some text and a "start" button. "Start" creates an instance of ParaFrame, hides the StartFrame, and shows the ParaFrame instance. Paraframe has a bunch of widgets for the user to select a file and how to analyze it. When all the fields are entered, an "Analyze" button pops up, which (when clicked) instantiates the custom DataHandler class, sets its parameters according to the user selections, calls a DataHandler method which analyzes the data, hides itself, and instantiates+shows the ResultsFrame. Not surprisingly, the ResultsFrame shows the results of the analysis.

I want to add a "Start Over" control which will destroy everything (all the frames, panels, the DataHandler instance, etc.) and display a fresh StartFrame instance, or otherwise destroy everything *except* the already-instantiated-but-hidden StartFrame, showing that frame again, but I'm at a loss.

A simplified example follows:

```
import wx

class StartFrame(wx.Frame):
    """App start frame"""
    FRAME_MIN_SIZE = (900,600)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent,
         id=wx.ID_ANY, title="LOD Calculator", size=wx.Size(900,600),
         style=wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.startpnl = wx.Panel(self)

        self.startvsizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.startbtnsizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self.startpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Start Analysis",\
         size = (200,60))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._OnStart)
        self.startbtnsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startbtnsizer.Add(self.btn, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.startbtnsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startvsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startvsizer.Add(self.startbtnsizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 25))
        self.startvsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.startvsizer)

    def _OnStart(self,event):
        self.frm2 = ParaFrame(None)
        self.Hide()
        self.frm2.Show()

class ParaFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Data load frame"""
    FRAME_MIN_SIZE = (950,800)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent,
         id=wx.ID_ANY, title="LOD Calculator", size=wx.Size(950,800),
         style=wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.analyzebtn = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, u"Analyze",\
         wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.vsizer.Add(self.analyzebtn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.vsizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 25))
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        self.analyzebtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._analyze)

    def _analyze(self, event):
        dhandler = DataHandler(self)
        dhandler.data = "a bunch"
        dhandler.data2 = " of data"
        dhandler.data3 = " goes here"
        dhandler._analyzeData()
        self.resfrm = ResultFrame(self, dhandler.data, dhandler.data2)
        self.Hide()
        self.resfrm.Show()

class DataHandler:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.data = ''
        self.data2 = ''
        self.data3 = ''

    def _analyzeData(self):
        anastr = self.data + self.data2 + " gets analyzed"
        print(anastr)

class ResultFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, targets, dftables):
        super(ResultFrame, self).__init__(parent, title="results", size=(1535,935))
        self.targets = targets
        self.dftables = dftables
        self.InitUI()
        self.Layout()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.restartbtn = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, u"Start Over",\
         wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.vsizer.Add(self.restartbtn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.vsizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 25))
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        self.restartbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRestart)

### this is where I try to destroy the ParaFrame instance and everything spawned by it, unsuccessfully
    def OnRestart(self, event):
        frm.frm2.Destroy()
        frm.Show()

def main():
    import wx.lib.mixins.inspection
    app = wx.App()
    frm = StartFrame(None)
    frm.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show(refreshTree=True)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, in the ResultFrame I have a "Start Over" button bound to a method in which I try to destroy the ParaFrame instance (and thus the DataHandler and ResultFrame instances spawned from it) by using `frm.frm2.Destroy()`, but get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\stackexchange code.py", line 102, in OnRestart
    frm.frm2.Destroy()
NameError: name 'frm' is not defined
```

If I change the line to just `frm2.Destroy()`, I get the same error, but stating `name 'frm2' is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I accomplish my goal? I'm still newish to OOP and quite new to wxPython, so any help is appreciate it. All I want is for that button to destroy everything and display the/an initial StartFrame again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you create each class without a parent, you can use `self.Destroy()` after creating the next frame in the chain, without it destroying any `children`. (Pass any data required as a parameter other than parent)

So your code, looks something like this:

```
import wx

class StartFrame(wx.Frame):
    """App start frame"""
    FRAME_MIN_SIZE = (900,600)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent,
         id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Load Calculator", size=wx.Size(900,600))

        self.startpnl = wx.Panel(self)

        self.startvsizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.startbtnsizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self.startpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Start Analysis",\
         size = (200,60))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._OnStart)
        self.startbtnsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startbtnsizer.Add(self.btn, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.startbtnsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startvsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startvsizer.Add(self.startbtnsizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 25))
        self.startvsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.startpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.startvsizer)

    def _OnStart(self,event):
        frm2 = ParaFrame(None)
        frm2.Show()
        self.Destroy()

class ParaFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Data load frame"""
    FRAME_MIN_SIZE = (950,800)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent,
         id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Load Calculator", size=wx.Size(900,600))

        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.analyzebtn = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, u"Analyze",\
         wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.vsizer.Add(self.analyzebtn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.vsizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 25))
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        self.analyzebtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._analyze)

    def _analyze(self, event):
        dhandler = DataHandler(self)
        dhandler.data = "a bunch"
        dhandler.data2 = " of data"
        dhandler.data3 = " goes here"
        dhandler._analyzeData()
        resfrm = ResultFrame(None, dhandler.data, dhandler.data2)
        resfrm.Show()
        self.Destroy()

class DataHandler:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.data = ''
        self.data2 = ''
        self.data3 = ''

    def _analyzeData(self):
        anastr = self.data + self.data2 + " gets analyzed"
        print(anastr)

class ResultFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, targets, dftables):
        super(ResultFrame, self).__init__(parent, title="Results", size=(900,600))
        self.targets = targets
        self.dftables = dftables
        self.InitUI()
        self.Layout()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.restartbtn = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, u"Start Over",\
         wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.vsizer.Add(self.restartbtn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.vsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.vsizer, wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 25))
        self.mainsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        self.restartbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRestart)

### this is where I try to destroy the ParaFrame instance and everything spawned by it, unsuccessfully
    def OnRestart(self, event):
        frm = StartFrame(None)
        frm.Show()
        self.Destroy()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frm = StartFrame(None)
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! One question -- how would I implement a method like `.Destroy()` for the `DataHandler` class?

Comment: I don't think it would matter but you could `del dhandler` after destroying `ParaFrame`.